# Drupal 7 - Is there any way to show specific groups in list?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, organic-groups

Let me explain it...I want to create 4 main groups for my platform where every user can see. So i want to have a list of these groups like the default user-group list that comes with OG module.

I have created a link in user menu where each user can see his own groups (user-groups) and now i want to create a link in main menu that will show **only** the list with the 4 main groups of the platform.

Are there any ideas or advice on how to proceed?

My first thinking was to create a user (system user, not real person) who will create the 4 groups. And then i would use his user-group url for the main menu item. So i created this user and the groups but i can't get the path of his group-list and add it to the main menu so any user can see them because this view shows the groups of the current logged in user.

Looking forward to your advice! if there are any questions let me know.

PS: My setup is Drupal 7 and Organic groups. The 4 groups are public.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what i' ve done.

I created a view and edited the filter criteria.

Specifically:

Content: Published (Yes)
Content: Group (= Group)
Content: Title (begins Scenario)
Content: Author uid (= myuserid)

So now i have a menu item when clicked it shows a table with the 4 main groups of the user only!

any better approach or advice is welcome!